# Elastic Search - Cannot initialize SSL - Certificate issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, ssl, pyspark

I'm trying to fetch data from Elastic Search(version:7.13.4) through PySpark. However, I'm getting this error.

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Cannot initialize SSL - parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
```

**My code:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from functools import reduce
import time, datetime, argparse,math,configparser,urllib3
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession,Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,lit,to_utc_timestamp,hour,dayofweek,round,lower,col,unix_timestamp,pandas_udf,PandasUDFType,mean,date_format,concat,when,first,last,count,sum,ceil,max,asc
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType,IntegerType,StringType
from datetime import timedelta
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.exceptions import NotFoundError
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import*

query = """{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}"""


df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes", "elasticsearch-svc.namespace") \
                                                         .option("es.port","9200") \
                                                         .option("es.read.metadata", "false") \
                                                         .option("es.mapping.date.rich", "false") \
                                                         .option("es.query", query) \
                                                         .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "elastic-username") \
                                                         .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "elastic-password") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.location","file:////my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.p12") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.pass","mypassword") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.type","PKCS12") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location","file:////my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.p12") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass","mypassword") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl","true") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed","true") \
                                                         .load("my_index")
```

**Complete error:**

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o673.load. :
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot
> detect ES version - typically this happens if the
> network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a
> WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'     at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:340)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:225)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg(DefaultSource.scala:223)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:229)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema(DefaultSource.scala:229)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:233)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:233)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.schema(DefaultSource.scala:233)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:403)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Cannot
> initialize SSL - parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data
> isn't an object ID (tag = 48)     at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:175)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.getSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:160)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:129)
> at
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
> at
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
> at
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
> at
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
> at
> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.doExecute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:685)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.execute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:664)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:116)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:432)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
> at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.mainInfo(RestClient.java:745)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:330)
> ... 23 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters
> failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)  at
> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:816)
> at
> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2018)
> at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)  at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(SSLSocketFactory.java:200)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.loadKeyManagers(SSLSocketFactory.java:215)
> at
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:173)
> ... 40 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() --
> data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)    at
> sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.(ObjectIdentifier.java:257)
> at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getOID(DerInputStream.java:314)
> at
> com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineInit(PBES2Parameters.java:267)
> at
> java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293)
> at
> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:812)
> ... 45 more

I thought the keystore type might be the problem and tried to convert the .p12 files to .jks file and it is also not working

**error:**

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got fixed once I converted the `.p12` file to `.jks` file using `keytool`

cmd to convert the `.p12` file to `.jks` file =>

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.p12 -destkeystore /my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.jks -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass <password_of_.p12_file>`

You may get the below error if you try to execute the above command on a computer with `openjdk-1.8.0`.  To avoid the error execute the `keytool` command from a computer with `openjdk version "16"`

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
```

## Working code:

```
df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes", "elasticsearch-svc.namespace") \
                                                         .option("es.port","9200") \
                                                         .option("es.read.metadata", "false") \
                                                         .option("es.mapping.date.rich", "false") \
                                                         .option("es.query", query) \
                                                         .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "elastic-username") \
                                                         .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "elastic-password") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.location","file:////my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.jks") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.pass","mypassword") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.type","JKS") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location","file:////my-storage/ssl_certificates/elastic-certificates.jks") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass","mypassword") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl","true") \
                                                         .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed","true") \
                                                         .load("my_index")
```